# can one column in a table reference three primary keys in three different table

Tags: reference, foreign-keys, primary-key, user-profile

I want to reference UserProfile_tbl(UserId) to three Primary Keys as Student(Regno), Faculty(Regno), Admin(adminId). Is this Possible? I am using UserProfile Table for Login.